# How does Bloomberg use the OIS curve to get the zero rates?

Tags: bloomberg, zero-coupon, ois-discounting

I'm trying to reproduce the zero rates using the market rates, but I have not been able to. I read the Bloomberg's "Building the Interest Rate Curve" paper and followed the formulas exactly but that didn't help as well.

For example, for the 1-week GBP OIS:
Discount factor = 1 / (1 + 3.42880% *  7 /365) = 0.999343
Zero rate = -365/7 * ln(0.999343) = 3.42767% (BBG zero rate 3.42816%)

Could anyone please help point any mistake here? Thank you in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you take screenshots, it helps if you do not cut off the important parts - or at least mention where the screenshot is from. Usually, `ICVS` is where one would look for details about interest rates.

However, I am almost certain your screenshot is actually from the `5) Curves` Tab of `SWPM`.

Your calculation is correct for the continuously compounded Zero rate as shown on ICVS. The dicount factor is computed from the zero rate.

[image]

However, if you hover over the value in SWPM, you will see that it uses the specific day-count convention and compound frequency of the swap itself.

[image]

The first set of values is relatively simple.
[image]

Overall, replicating curve stripping (not just Bloomberg) exactly is quite difficult. It is not only about knowing the correct method but also about taking into account all calendars, interpolation etc.

Comment: I understand thank you so much for your answer! Indeed this is from the SWPM - I had assumed the zero rates for a given OIS curve would always be the same - but clearly it depends on the application of it.